# what is the difference between .function() and a function(args) in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, conventions

I have a question i have always written functions in javascript for returning or setting values of other elements like so:

```
function test(x, y){
   return x*y;
}
```

and call the function like so:

```
test(20, 50);
```

but in libraries like jquery you also see functions like so:

```
var test = something.test();
```

so my question is what is the difference between the following functions `.test() or test()` or are they the same and how is this other way of writing a function called?

and how do you write a `.function()`

Hope to learn something new, sorry if this is a bit random but i am just very curious.

Comment: Surely a something.test() function is just a function called on the object something ?

Comment: It's just a function that was assigned to an object property. This is called a "method".

Comment: @MuthuKumaran Don't we have a JS-specific one that also details how `this` works?

Comment: @Bergi: What do you think about the one I added?

Comment: @Cerbrus Looks good

Comment: check this answer hope this will help to understand better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46471369/5236174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a function. It is called as `function()`

```js
function test(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

console.log(test(2,3));
```

This is a method of an object. It is a function that is declared in the object and is called as `object.function()`

```js
var myObject = {
  test: function (a, b) {
    return a * b;
  }
}

console.log(myObject.test(2,3));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `something.test` is a property of `something`, that happens to be a function.

`test()`, on the other hand, is just a function, accessible in your current scope.

Here's a extremely simplified example:

```js
const someObj = {
  test: function(){
     console.log('foo!');
  }
}

function test(){
   console.log('bar!');
}

someObj.test();
test();
```

Comment: oke so how would this look in code? how  is jquery do do things like:  $('element').value() how does this look in code?

Comment: thanks for the explaination! i will accept your answer!

Comment: You don't really have accept this answer. A better, more complete answer can be found in the linked duplicate targets.

Comment: @FutureCake: The `$` function simply returns an object with an attribute `value` (among many others) that is a function.